# How to show that $(L_{\alpha} x)_{k} = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} {\alpha}^{kl} x_l$ is a bounded operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

The following question was asked in my assignment of Hilbert operators and I am not able to make any significant progress on this question.

> Question: Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. Show that the formula $(L_{\alpha} x)_{k} = \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} {\alpha}^{kl} x_l$ defines a bounded operator $L_{\alpha} : l^2(\mathbb{N}^{*}) \to l^2(\mathbb{N}^{*})$ and $||L_{\alpha} || $ $\leq  \sqrt{ \frac{\pi} {log(1/ \alpha)}}$.

Attempt: I thought of using only the definition not any result( maybe because I am not sure what result I should use to prove this). I am not able to prove that operator is bounded using the definition and also to prove the inequality I used the definition but I am not able to make significant progress.

Can you please guide me on how to solve this question?

Comment: The norm can be estimated above by ${\alpha\over 1-\alpha}$ which is worse than the one given in the answer.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But how to prove that the operator is bounded? Also, can you please elaborate on your comment by showing some calculations? That will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general fact: if an operator is given by
$$(Ax)_k=\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_{kl}x_l$$ then
$$\|A\|\le \left (\sum_{k,l=1}^\infty |a_{kl}|^2\right )^{1/2}$$
The proof is straightfoward by applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.
$$\|Ax\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left |\sum_{l=1}^\infty a_{kl}x_l\right |^2\le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^\infty |a_{kl}|^2\|x\|^2$$
In the OP case $a_{kl}=\alpha^{kl}$ hence
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{l=1}^\infty \alpha^{2kl}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\alpha^{2k}\over 1-\alpha^{2k}}\le {1\over 1-\alpha^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\alpha^{2k}={\alpha^2\over (1-\alpha^2)^2}$$
Hence $\displaystyle\|L_\alpha\|\le {\alpha\over 1-\alpha^2}.$
The estimate is worse than the one given in OP.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: You welcome. Do you have any hint for this better estimate ? When you take a log of each term of the matrix you get $(k+l)\log \alpha.$ This remind me of the Hilbert matrix $k+l$ whose norm is $\sqrt{\pi}.$ I have no idea how to connect one with the other.

Comment: No, I actually don't have but in my assignement on bounded operators , I am finding so many typos. I am satisfied with your bound. I am sorry. The professor never bothered much about the questions in the assignment and we were left to ourself. I am having a really hard time in this course.